# setStartLineColor and setEndLineColor not working for timeline view

Tags: android, kotlin, timeline

I am trying to the change color of the timeline based on position and status from an adapter. but it is not working. I am trying this dynamically using conditions as follows:

```
 private fun setLineColor(holder: TimeLineViewHolder, position: Int, status: OrderStatus) {
    when (position) {
        0 -> {
            when (status) {
                OrderStatus.COMPLETED -> holder.timeline.setEndLineColor(R.color.colorAccent, 1)
                OrderStatus.INACTIVE -> holder.timeline.setEndLineColor(R.color.grey_color, 1)
                OrderStatus.ACTIVE -> holder.timeline.setEndLineColor(R.color.grey_color, 1)
            }
        }
        mFeedList.size - 1 -> {
            when (status) {
                OrderStatus.COMPLETED -> holder.timeline.setStartLineColor(R.color.colorAccent, 2)
                OrderStatus.INACTIVE -> holder.timeline.setStartLineColor(R.color.grey_color, 2)
                OrderStatus.ACTIVE -> holder.timeline.setStartLineColor(R.color.grey_color, 2)
            }
        }
        else -> {
            when (status) {
                OrderStatus.COMPLETED -> {
                    holder.timeline.setStartLineColor(R.color.colorAccent, 0)
                    holder.timeline.setEndLineColor(R.color.colorAccent, 0)
                }
                OrderStatus.INACTIVE -> {
                    holder.timeline.setStartLineColor(R.color.grey_color, 0)
                    holder.timeline.setEndLineColor(R.color.grey_color, 0)
                }
                OrderStatus.ACTIVE -> {
                    holder.timeline.setStartLineColor(R.color.colorAccent, 0)
                    holder.timeline.setEndLineColor(R.color.grey_color, 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but the color is showing as grey only. Also referred [#21](https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View/issues)

I found so many queries about this in github but it points to another link but that is also not working. [this is a link](https://github.com/anton46/Android-StepsView)

the only thing I need to be done is till the current position I need Accent color and after that a disabled color. Does anyone have a solution for this?.

Comment: whats the library which you are using for timeline view?

Comment: https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View this library

Answer (score 0):

Check this one i think this can fix your problem

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.po10cio:TimeLineView:1.0.2'
}

<me.jerryhanks.stepview.TimeLineView
 android:id="@+id/timelineView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
```

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6540